Differences Between Human Pose Estimation and Facial Landmark Models in Structure
I have a question regarding the structural differences between human pose estimation models and facial landmark models. While I understand that both models aim to predict keypoints, I wonder how the structure of these models might differ due to the different domains they target.
If there is no big difference, for example, would it be feasible to use a pose estimation model like YOLOv8 Pose to predict facial landmarks?
